# Does `mount -oloop` use direct IO by default (when the kernel is new enough)?

Tags: mount, loop-device

Since the kernel started supporting it, `losetup` was modified to enable direct IO by default.  This can avoid having redundant page cache and also has performance advantages.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/losetup.8.html

> --direct-io[=on|off]
>
> Enable or disable direct I/O for the backing file.  The
>                 optional argument can be either on or off.  If the argument is
>                 omitted, it defaults to on.

I noticed, when the kernel added this feature, [one commit mentions adding a feature specifically for `mount -oloop`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=ab1cb278bc7027663adbfb0b81404f8398437e11).  Has `mount -oloop` also been modified so that it defaults to enabling direct IO (if the kernel is new enough)?  I can't find it mentioned in the documentation.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think this has been implemented so far (util-linux v2.31.1).

`mount` and `losetup` use common code to create loop devices, but the `loopcxt_set_dio()` function is only called inside the `main()` function of `losetup.c`.

https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/search?q=loopcxt_set_dio

https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/search?q=LOOP_SET_DIRECT_IO